# create invalid JSON for negative test in Typescript

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I'm finding it difficult to work around TS (fantastic) static typing to create some invalid data for input to a  negative test case.

I am trying to fix an error where invalid JSON (double quotes in the value) can be passed from the client.  I have it fixed, but want to be assured of such in a unit test.

So I want to call a method with some invalid JSON to check that bad data will be rejected.

```
    postId: "1234",
    comment: "an invalid "comment"
  };
```

Can anyone help me find a way to write the test data to replicate the invalid JSON?

```
//ts-ignore
```

isn't helping me.  I know I am missing something obvious.  TIA

Playground at https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-glitter-q8jn7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parsing `args` as JSON will always evaluate to true because JS objects are JSON serializable. So you can modify your function to the following and it should get the job done.

```
function acceptComment(args: MyBespokeMutationArgsType): boolean {
  if (!isJsonString(`{ "comment": "${args.comment}" }`)) return false;
  console.log("comment will be processed");
  return true;
}
```

And speaking of passing invalid input, you can use template strings.

```
const input = {
  postId: "1234",
  comment: `valid "comment`
};
```